# convert combination of replace methods onto one

Tags: javascript

I have a combination of replace methods. How can I convert them to one:

```
.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\,|\?|\!|\:|\./g,'').replace("'", "_")
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: Pass a function, and you can use a single `replace()` call.

Comment: FYI, you can simplify `\,|\?|\!|\:|\.` to `[,?!:.]`

Comment: `,`, `!` and `:` are not special characters in `regex`, they don't need to be escaped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's *possible* with a replacer function which alternates between the different possibilities, captures the matching subpattern, and checks which subpattern was matched in the replacer function, but it's really ugly. Your current solution is much easier to read.

```js
const string = '  here is multiple spaces consolidated, punctuation removed!! and apostrophes don\'t exist!   ';
const result = string
  .replace(
    /(\s+)|(\,|\?|\!|\:|\.)|(')/g,
    (match, g1, g2, g3) => (
      g1 ? ' ' :
        g2 ? '' :
          '_'
    )
  );
console.log(result);
```

I'd use your original version with a slight tweak: use a character set in the second `replace` instead, it'll be easier to read.

```js
const string = '  here is multiple spaces consolidated, punctuation removed!! and apostrophes don\'t exist!   ';
const result = string
  .replace(/\s+/g, " ")
  .replace(/[,?!:.]/g,'')
  .replace("'", "_");
console.log(result);
```